# How to fill selected file name in text box in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is the code.

```
<button ngf-select ng-model="b.files" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="uploadMode=1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Pick Image
</button>

<input type="text" ng-model="f.name" value="b.files[0].name"><br><br>

<ul>
    <li>{{b.files[0].name}}</li>
</ul>
```

When user selecting a file to upload, it is displaying in ul - li. But i want same file name to be displayed in text box also. For that i am setting text box value to value="b.files[0].name". But its not working.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Value is always overwritten by ng-model if present, so you should use this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="b.files[0].name">
```